# How facebook's FB.api works?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to facebook developers. My requirement to publish a post in user's wall through my app. But since publish_actions is deprecated from last August, I tried to use FB.api methods.

I initiated the quick setup using [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart#loading) and then I followed the procedures mentioned [here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api#examples) 
But it didn't work well and I didn't get any responses from Facebook.

Did I miss any procedures that I should follow?

This code is given in by facebook and I tried with this.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({

    appId: '/*theID*/',
    autoLogAppEvents: true,
    xfbml: false, // I'm not using social plugins, set to false
    version: 'v3.2'
  });

};

function postToWall() { //Using this function to post on the wall
  var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
  FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
    message: body
  }, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
      alert('Error occured');
      console.log('Response: ' + response);
    } else {
      alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I think you should at least make the effort to provide some examples of what you've tried to implement previously?

Comment: I added the codes in the questions @JO3-W3B-D3V

Comment: Just to be sure, you are calling the function, right? Are you getting any error messages in the console? Edit: Did a quick, minimal test and got `"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."` Edit2: Added login before requesting stuff, and it worked right away. Check the bottom of [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/examples) for the login code.

Comment: the feed endpoint for user profiles needs the publish_actions permission, so i am not sure what you are trying to achieve here - as you know, that permission is deprecated. you need to use share options: for example, FB.ui.